# What's the difference between a DoubleLinkedQueue and a ListQueue in Dart?

Tags: list, iterator, linked-list, queue, dart

The Dart core API has two classes that implement the [`Queue<E>`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_collection/Queue.html) interface, [`DoubleLinkedQueue<E>`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_collection/DoubleLinkedQueue.html) and [`ListQueue<E>`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_collection/ListQueue.html).

The documentation of both classes is almost identical, the only difference that is explicitly mentioned is the following note in the `ListQueue<E>` documentation:

> Operations like `removeAll` and `removeWhere` are very inefficient. If those are needed, use a `DoubleLinkedQueue` instead.

What is the actual difference between them implementation-wise and when should which implementation be used?

Comment: I personally think that `Queue` should not have `removeWhere` or `removeAll`; that's not part of what makes a queue. I'd argue this is bad design. Of course, this doesn't answer your question about the differences between them, which is why this is only a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yeah, the `LinkedList` class is also quite strange. It requires the elements it lists to extend a certain class. Not really a generic implementation. I also see no difference between a `Queue` and a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `DoubleLinkedQueue` is basically a Queue implemented on top of a double-linked list. This means that removing elements at arbitrary positions in it is fast, since it only requires the adjustment of pointers.

The `ListQueue` is implemented on top of a List. First and last are indices into the list. In general this is the more efficient implementation, since it has less memory-overhead than the double-linked list.

You can see both implementations [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/collection/queue.dart)

Most of the time you want to use the `ListQueue`. For that reason, the `Queue` interface defaults to the ListQueue (i.e. `Queue()` returns a `ListQueue`).

The `DoubleLinkedQueue` implementation is mostly useful if you need to selectively remove elements inside the queue. It's a relatively rare scenario, and the main-reason the class is in the dart-libraries, is that the `DoubleLinkedQueue` existed before the `ListQueue`. Since we already had the `DoubleLinkedQueue` we kept it. If we had started out with the ListQueue we probably wouldn't have added the `DoubleLinkedQueue`.